# Script Editor Range Trouble Shoot

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am almost finished writing a code to automatically send reminder emails when a staff's submission is due. However, I need help in figuring out how to automatically insert the staff member's name into the emails.

I am a complete novice at writing code so my language around the question is somewhat limited. I've taught myself by piecing things together and trial and error. Here is a link to my sheet if needed:

I have posted my code below: in the text for "msg" I have tried writing:
 var msg = "Hello" +staff_info_values+ "\n \nThis is a reminder that your EPICS session is due in one week.\n \nPlease don't hesitate to contact us or your unit coach with any questions." but of course this returns the entire range staff values.

My entire code:

```html
function CustomEmail() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[0]);
var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
var startRow = 2;
//range of days left
var range = sheet.getRange(2,3,lastRow-startRow+1,1 );
var numRows = range.getNumRows();
var days_left_values = range.getValues();
//range of staff names  
range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow-startRow+1, 1);
var staff_info_values = range.getValues();
//range of emails
range = sheet.getRange(2, 2, lastRow-startRow+1, 1);
var staff_info_email = range.getValues();
//range of coach emails
range = sheet.getRange(2, 4, lastRow-startRow+1, 1);
var coach_info_email = range.getValues(); 
//range of cjm1 emails
range = sheet.getRange(2, 5, lastRow-startRow+1, 1);
var cjm1_info_email = range.getValues();
//range of cjm2 emails
range = sheet.getRange(2, 6, lastRow-startRow+1, 1);
var cjm2_info_email = range.getValues();
//range of FTO emails
range = sheet.getRange(2, 7, lastRow-startRow+1, 1);
var fto_info_email = range.getValues();
//range of EPICS Lead emails
range = sheet.getRange(2, 18, lastRow-startRow+1, 1);
var epics_lead_info_email = range.getValues();
 
var warning_count = 0;  
var msg = "Hello,\n \nThis is a reminder that your EPICS session is due in one week.\n \nPlease don't hesitate to contact us or your unit coach with any questions.";
var msg2 = "Hello [insert staff name],\n \nThis is an automated message from the EPICS unit. \n \nAccording to records, your EPICS coaching session is two weeks overdue. Please schedule a session with your coach to be removed from overdue status. \n \nPlease advise if you feel you have received this notification in error.";
var msg3 = "This is an alert for the EPICS Lead Officer that [insert staff name] is two months overdue for a session."
  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) 
  {
    var days_left = days_left_values[i][0];
    if(days_left == 7) 
    {
      var reminder_name = staff_info_values[i][0];
      var emailaddress = staff_info_email[i][0];
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailaddress, "EPICS Session Reminder", msg);
      Logger.log(msg);
    }
    if(days_left == -14) 
    {
      var reminder_name = staff_info_values[i][0];
      var emailaddress = staff_info_email[i][0];
      var coachaddress = coach_info_email[i][0];
      var cjm1address = cjm1_info_email[i][0];
      var cjm2address = cjm2_info_email[i][0];
      var ftoaddress = fto_info_email[i][0];
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailaddress + "," + coach_info_email + "," + cjm1_info_email + "," + cjm2_info_email + "," + fto_info_email, "EPICS Session Overdue Reminder", msg2);
      Logger.log(msg2);
    }
    if(days_left == -60) 
    {
      var reminder_name = staff_info_values[i][0];
      var leadaddress = epics_lead_info_email[i][0];
      MailApp.sendEmail(leadaddress, "EPICS Session Alert", msg3);
      Logger.log(msg3);
    }
  }   

}
```

Comment: Please post your code here so people can have look at and suggest edits. Link to sheet or script editor is a not a preferred method! Thanks!

Comment: Welcome. The first suggestion is to follow the [tour] and checkout [ask], because the question doesn't show any search/research effort as is suggested to include on the questions. Also checkout the wiki of [tag:gooble-apps-script] as it include useful links.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance and your patience. I will review the how to ask and edit the original post.

Comment: The code you tired `"Hello" +staff_info_values+ "\n` returns the entire list, but here you got individual values `var reminder_name = staff_info_values[i][0];`. How did you manage that? What is different? If you figure that out, you will figure out the answer

Comment: Thank you for the direction! I will work on it